# Dialogflow BrowseCarousel not working after Permission granted

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In my flow there are three handlers:

- Store finder: when user ask "where is store near me?", it triggers the `actions.intent.PERMISSION` that ask user for his precise location.
- Store finder - yes: if user replies "yes", this will be triggered and the nearest stores will be shown (based on lat/long extracted from request)
- Store finder - no: if user replies "no", this will be triggered and only the stores in a specific city will be showed.

The json response will be the same in the two handler for `yes` and `no` reply.

```
{
      "payload": {
        "google": {
          "expectUserResponse": true,
          "richResponse": {
            "items": [
              {
                "simpleResponse": {
                  "textToSpeech": "Store near: Address Number City.\n Now: OPEN."
                }
              },
              {
                "carouselBrowse": {
                  "items": [
                    {
                      "title": "title 0",
                      "openUrlAction": {
                        "url": "https://website.it/?0"
                      },
                      "description": "description",
                      "image": {
                        "url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/5048136?s=460&v=4",
                        "accessibilityText": "empty"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "title": "title 1",
                      "openUrlAction": {
                        "url": "https://website.it/?1"
                      },
                      "description": "description",
                      "image": {
                        "url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/5048136?s=460&v=4",
                        "accessibilityText": "empty"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "title": "title 2",
                      "openUrlAction": {
                        "url": "https://website.it/?2"
                      },
                      "description": "description",
                      "image": {
                        "url": "https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/5048136?s=460&v=4",
                        "accessibilityText": "empty"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          },
          "userStorage": "{\"lat\":45.4627124, \"long\": 9.1076928}"
        }
      },
      "outputContexts": [
        {
          "name": "projects/project-name/agent/sessions/ABppEePAPYRhvT9Pcwmu3S61Ka12DUN5gmem7v0p/contexts/context-name",
          "lifespanCount": 1,
          "parameters": {
            "Data": ""
          }
        }
      ],
      "followupEventInput": {
        "parameters": {
          "data": {
            "listSelect": {}
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**Problem**

When I reply "no", the BrowseCarousel works. When I reply "yes", the BrowseCarousel does not work.

I cannot find the reason of this. The json response is exactly the same in the two different intents.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved.

The answer is: the simulator is broken for this particular event. When using a real device the browsecarousel is working as expected.

**USE A REAL DEVICE IF YOU WANT TO SEE EXACTLY WHAT THE RESULT LOOK LIKE.**